# Can a C++ lambda constructor argument capture the constructed variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

The following *compiles*. But is there ever any sort of dangling reference issue?

```
    class Foo {
         Foo(std::function<void(int)> fn) { /* etc */ }
    }

    void f(int i, Foo& foo) { /* stuff with i and foo */ }

    Foo foo([&foo](int i){f(i, foo);});
```

Seems to work. (The real lambda is of course more complicated.)

Comment: Probably worth noting that if you use the lambda in the constructor, bad things could happen.

Comment: if you capture it by copy you get a warning with clang `variable is uninitialized when used within its own initialization`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But is there ever any sort of dangling reference issue?

That depends entirely on what you're doing with `Foo`. Here's an example that *would* have dangling reference issues:

```
struct Foo {
     Foo() = default;
     Foo(std::function<void(int)> fn) : fn(fn) { }
     std::function<void(int)> fn;
}

Foo outer;
{
    Foo inner([&inner](int i){f(i, inner);});
    outer = inner;
}
outer.fn(42); // still has reference to inner, which has now been destroyed
```

Comment: So it would be reasonable to say my pattern isn't any more dangerous than dangling references in general? The lifetime of my `foo` isn't an issue in this case. I found the construction rather weird, capturing a reference to an object that's still getting constructed.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Yeah, basically. Just weird.

Answer (score 5):

The lambda expression `[&foo](int i){f(i, foo);}` will lead compiler to generate a closure class something like this (but not totally correct) :

```
class _lambda
{
    Foo& mFoo; // foo is captured by reference

public:
    _lambda(Foo& foo) : mFoo(foo) {}

    void operator()(int i) const
    {
       f(i, mFoo);
    }
};
```

Therefore, the declaration `Foo foo([&foo](int i){f(i, foo);});` is treated as `Foo foo(_lambda(foo));`. Capturing `foo` itself when constructing does not has problem in this situation because only its address is required here (References are usually implemented via pointers).

The type `std::function<void(int)>` will internally copy construct this lambda type, which means that Foo's constructor argument `fn` holds a copy of `_lambda` object (that holds a reference (i.e., mFoo) to your `foo`).

These implies that dangling reference issue may arise in some situations, for example:

```
std::vector<std::function<void(int)>> vfn; // assume vfn live longer than foo

class Foo {
     Foo(std::function<void(int)> fn) { vfn.push_back(fn); }
}

void f(int i, Foo& foo) { /* stuff with i and foo */ }

Foo foo([&foo](int i){f(i, foo);});

....

void ff()
{
    // assume foo is destroyed already,
    vfn.pop_back()(0); // then this passes a dangling reference to f.
}
```

Comment: Is there "a closure class" in C++ language? I heard the lambda could be the closure function...but class?