# Using lambdas to throw template type's member as an exception

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Here is a simple version of a use case that I have been trying to investigate

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdexcept>
#include<memory>
#include<type_traits>
#include<string>

class intexception:public std::exception
{
    public:

        intexception(std::string m,int x):msg(m),g(x){}

        const char* what() const throw() { return msg.c_str(); }
        virtual ~intexception() throw(){}
        int getExceptInt()const { return g;}

    private:
        std::string msg;
        int g;
};

class Int
{ 
    public: 
        Int():m_ptr(nullptr){}
        Int(const int& x) : m_ptr(new int(x)) { }

        Int(const Int& in) : m_ptr( (in.get()) ? ( new int(*in.m_ptr) ) : ( nullptr ) ) {}
        Int& operator=(const Int&) = default;

        Int(Int&&) = default;
        Int& operator=(Int&&) = default;

        int get() const { return *m_ptr; }         

    private:
        std::unique_ptr<int>m_ptr;
}; 

class TypedInt
{
    public:
    template<typename T, 
        typename std::enable_if< std::is_same<typename std::decay<T>::type,int>::value || std::is_same<typename std::decay<T>::type,long>::value, 
                                 std::nullptr_t>::type = nullptr>

            explicit TypedInt (T& intid )
            : m_holder( intid ),
              m_throw ( [this]() { throw intexception("Integer Exception",static_cast<T>(this->get())); } )
              {}

    TypedInt():m_holder(),m_throw(std::function<void()>()){}

    TypedInt& operator=(TypedInt&&) = default;
    TypedInt(TypedInt&& other):m_holder(std::move(other.m_holder)),m_throw(std::move(other.m_throw)) {}

    TypedInt& operator=(const TypedInt&) = default;
    TypedInt(const TypedInt&) = default;

    int get() const { return m_holder.get(); }

    void Throw() { m_throw(); }

    private:
        Int m_holder;
        std::function<void()>m_throw;
};

void testThrow(TypedInt t)
{
    try
    {
        t.Throw();
    }
    catch(const intexception& e)
    {
        std::cout<<e.what()<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<e.getExceptInt()<<std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int z = 10;
    TypedInt t1(z);

    TypedInt t2;

    t2 = std::move(t1);

    testThrow(std::move(t2));
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles fine  without problems. However, it ends up in a segmentation fault.

I looked at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738655/can-a-c-lambda-constructor-argument-capture-the-constructed-variable) and I feel I might be facing a similar problem.

I have debugged this with gdb and I cant understand as to why this `get()` function is returning a `null` value for underlying integer in my `std::unique_ptr` member variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you construct `t1`, you construct its `m_throw` with:

```
m_throw ([this]() {
    throw intexception("Integer Exception",static_cast<T>(this->get()));
})
```

That is, `t1.m_throw` is holding onto `t1` (by pointer). It's throwing an `intexception` that is constructed from `t1.m_holder.get()`.

When you move that into `t2` - the actual underlying lambda in the `std::function` doesn't change. It's still trying to throw `t1.m_holder.get()`. The problem is, once you moved from `t1.m_holder` , dereferencing that underlying `unique_ptr` is invalid - which is the source of your segmentation fault.

You'll have to rebind the thrower to make sure that you're always throwing from `this`. The easiest would just be to pass in the `TypedInt` instance as an argument, then you don't have to worry about anything.

Answer (score 2):

You capture the `this` by value in the lambda. After all the moves, the `this` pointer you captured no longer points to a valid object.

The `this` capture does not "track" the object it is captured for.

You can try simply the implementation to capture the `intid` instead.

```
m_throw ( [intid]() {
  throw intexception("Integer Exception", static_cast<int>(intid));
} )
```

Else; if the lambda is required to use the current object, the `this` pointer could be passed in as an argument when the lambda is called. In this case the lambda seems "heavy" given the use case.

The best be to avoid the lambda and simply `throw` when required; with the values in the objects at the time of the `throw`.